# cUrl HttpPost parameters not recognized(?) by server

Tags: android, json, post, curl, httpclient

I am trying to fetch an authorization key from a server. In the documentation they state that I can retrieve one by executing the following curl command:

```
$ curl --data "grant_type=authorization_code&code=603372224265" https://gerard2.zportal.nl/api/v2/oauth/token`
```

I have followed the instructions from stackoverflow and produced the following:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    mAuthorizationCode = params[0];
    mSchoolCode = params[1];

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://" + mSchoolCode + ".zportal.nl/api/v2/oauth/token");
    try{
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(2);
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", mAuthorizationCode));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));

        HttpParams parameters = httppost.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(parameters, 45000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(parameters, 45000);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, line);
        }
    }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error", e);
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IO Error", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The response the server sends me is:

```
    E/ScheduleRetriever: {"response":{"status":500,"message":"Intern probleem op het portal.","details":"class org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'grant_type' is not present","eventId":767369,"startRow":0,"endRow":0,"totalRows":0,"data":[]}
```

While I did include the POST_parameter "grant_type". Can someone help me figure out why the server says that it did not receive the parameter grant_type?

Thanks.

*EDIT: The code I used expired apparently. Generated a new one and it totally works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be overriding the `Content-Type` of the POST request to `application/json` using the line `httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");`

This is most likely causing the server to misinterpret the data since the `Content-type` of the request should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Remove the following line and it should work:

```
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```